# Rotations in iOS if UIViewAutoresizing doesn't cut it

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, autoresize

I'm creating a view controller that has non-trivial rotation behavior. I can't find a way to get all my transformations to occur with only UIViewAutoresizing (I'm doing things like keeping by bottom bar at the same "absolute value" on the screen" while rotating buttons). What's the correct way to handle these type of rotation behaviors? Is there a way to disable auto resizing for a specific view and handle the rotations yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a view's `autoresizesSubviews` property to `NO`, that view will not apply autoresizing to its subviews.  You can do this in a xib or storyboard by unchecking the “Autoresizes Subviews” checkbox in the attributes inspector.

The correct place to programmatically lay out subviews is in the `layoutSubviews` method of your custom `UIView` subclass.  Your view will receive the `layoutSubviews` method whenever its size changes or when its `subviews` array changes.  You will receive it when the view is first being put on the screen, and inside the autorotation animation block.